# Does UIWebView auto prefetch pages?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, prefetch

Does UIWebView auto prefetch pages?

This is my situation:

The main page is a local HTML file containing 3 links to other local HTML files. In one of them I have an iframe that loads a page from the Internet. Could the UIWebView be attempting to prefetch this page silently?

I'm inclining to no, but I haven't found a definite answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView mimics a browser page, so if you open a local file which has an iframe that references a remote page then yes the iframe will attempt to load the remote page but not until that page is loaded as the WebView's active html page.